# How to wrap Chinese font in Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I used `canvas.fillText` to draw Chinese font in canvas, but the words didn't wrap. I read the canvas tutorial [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-wrap-text-tutorial/), but it splits words using space, which won't work for Chinese fonts. Could someone have an experience on this or just show me where to find the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `measureText()` to measure line width by adding one and one glyph until you get a value exceeding the available space which is where you wrap the text.

For example - I made this loop which will wrap the line when there is no more space available:

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/ERGWw/)**

```
var txt = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    i = 0, ...;

/// loop trough the txt which holds the string
for(; i < txt.length; i++) {

    /// measure current width
    lw = ctx.measureText(line).width;

    /// if within available space add a char to line
    if (lw < w - ctx.measureText(txt[i]).width) {
        line += txt[i];

    } else {
        /// didn't fit so draw what we have
        ctx.fillText(line, x, y);

        /// reset line with the left-over char
        line = txt[i];

        /// reset x (not used in demo) and increment y position
        x = 0;
        y += 50;
    }
}

/// if anything was left in line draw it here
if (line.length > 0) ctx.fillText(line, x, y);
```

PS: I didn't have a Chinese font handy for the demo but you'll see the principle.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works well with Chinese fonts.